# Untranslated (but important) content in Latin?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, contemporary-latin, ecclesiastical-latin

I have renewed my self-studies of Latin and I have observed that the greatest effect (and motivation) of studies comes from trying to translate important texts from the foreign language to English or my native language.

Therefore I have question - are there Latin texts that still are not translated in English language but which are worthy to be translated. I guess that there are lot of medieval and more late scientific texts which has only historical importance and which I don't want to translate. But maybe there are new texts appearing today?

I have found Latinitas Foundation sponsored by Vatican and their Certamen competition of poetry:
http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/index_en.htm
http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/institutions_connected/latinitas/documents/rc_latinitas_20040601_certamen-vaticanum_lt.html
These Vatican activities is one source of contemporary Latin texts that are being created now and which, probably, lack translation in English.

I can be happy with ecclesiastical texts as well but I am not sure whether I would like (or be ready) to translate poems.

Comment: This topic gets me excited: there is a *huge* swath of Latin literature that is not translated. Not even the complete works of Augustine is fully translated!

Comment: I would be happy to translate any of church fathers, including Augustine. If You know some untranslated work exactly I would be happy to hear. I hope that Latin version of those texts is available on Internet (they should be copyright-free).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I do know that last year Oxford started to put out a new grammar. They've only released one volume (*Oxford Latin Syntax, volume 1: The Simple Clause*) and I haven't seen it yet but at almost 1,500 pages it has to be, I suspect, fairly comprehensive. :) https://www.amazon.com/Oxford-Latin-Syntax-Simple-Clause/dp/0199283613/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1470075412&sr=8-1&keywords=harm+pinkster

Comment: @TomR, Yes, I'd be happy to draft up a quick reply, although I have trouble understanding what you mean by something having "only historical importance." (The *Sentences of Peter Lombard* are not fully translated, I believe, and yet were the textbook of all scholastics...I *hope* that makes them important.)

Comment: Also, would you mind cleaning up your question a little bit? I am not sure what the question is about *Latinitas*, and the question about grammar should probably be separated from your first query. Check out the [site tour](http://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) for more info.

Comment: In my opinion - anything written by Church fathers is important. Scientific texts (physics, math, botany, medicine) of 15th-18th centuries can be qualified as unimportant texts, because exact sciences have different opninion what is important and what is not (what is relevant for the advancement of Science here and now). OK, I will have a look on Sentences, that can be sufficient for me.

Comment: Right now this question is extremely broad, as comments have suggested.  It's impossible to list all the Latin texts that fit your definition of "important" that haven't been translated into English here.  Thus, you should divide the question into several questions, asked separately.  For example, 1) untranslated church fathers, 2) untranslated scholastics, 3) untranslated contemporary poetry, etc.

Comment: The question about grammars should also be separate, but as it would be a resource recommendation-type question, it would need to be brought up at [Request for most-needed resource questions](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/188/12).

Comment: I've put your question "on hold" until you get a chance to narrow/clarify it, at which point it can be easily reopened.

Comment: This is a very interesting question, and it will surely be reopened once you narrow it down. I suggest asking for a specific kind of text (your favorite topic, era or author, for example). You can always ask a separate question about some other kind of text later, so making the question more specific doesn't permanently restrict you.